# How do i use fgetc with gcc compiler

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, gcc

I am trying to get 2 inputs from a user:

the first one is a size which i get using scanf.
the next input is a string of unknown size,
and the problem is that the first char on the input is the "enter" the user pressed from the line before therefor i dont get an input at all.
I will just note that on visual studio its completely fine! the problem is only on my mac and on my friends linux.
here is the code:

```
int main()
    {
        int size;
        char* inputString;
        printf("Enter the number of computers:");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        if (size == 1)
        {
            printf("Only one computer\n");
            return;
        }
    inputString = malloc(stringSize);
    inputString = inputStrings(stdin, stringSize);
 }
char *inputStrings(FILE* fp, int size)
{
    //The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch = 0;
    int len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if (!str)return str;
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n')
    {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size)
        {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 16));
            if (!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `getchar`. To use `getchar` with gcc you have to call it.

Comment: my bad i meant to write fgetc

Comment: *"the first char on the input is the "enter" the user pressed from the line before"* Yes, that's true, that's how `scanf` works, so you need to call `getchar` on the line after `scanf`, to eat the newline.

Comment: Code that *compiles* would be helpful

Comment: There is a memory leak with `inputString = malloc(stringSize);` because you immediately discard the pointer on re-assigning it the one returned from `inputStrings()`.

Comment: Thanks user3386109, That fixed my issue!

Comment: Code has a edge case problem with `inputStrings(FILE* fp, 0)` or any negative `size`.  Suggest `if (size <= 1) { error_message()`